# WSO2 BAM ESB LogEvent Authentication failed! admin

Tags: logging, wso2, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

I have some errors in the BAM console due to an Authentication situation:

I'm trying to use logevent appender from ESB 4.8.1 to publish events to BAM 2.5.0, I have an external LDAP where my users and roles are.  I have created a role with publish events premission and assigned to an user in the primary user store.
In the log4j.properties of the ESB I have specified the user mentioned above and the tcp url of the BAM server.
After I start the ESB I got a message in BAM console saying the user I created is connected and a bit later I got around 20 messages as follows:

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.authentication.Authenticator} - Authentication failed! admin. This user is not permitted to publish events {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.authentication.Authenticator}
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} - user admin connected {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge}

If I login to the BAM console and explore de Cassandra cluster in the EVENT_KS there is a column collection named log_0_ESB_yyyy_mm_dd and it has a lot of records.

I would like to know how can I get rid of those errors in the BAM console ??

I can give more information if needed, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same error. The error message is quite misleading in my opinion as eventually I found that adding the namespace `xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"` when setting the ESB BAM stream variables fixed my problem. So instead of

`<property name="mon_message_timestamp" expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>`

use

`<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="mon_message_timestamp" expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>`

Please, let me know if this fixes your problem!